# Obter dois trechos de uma string confusa

Tags: string, visual-basic-6, interpolação-de-string

*É muito simples minha pergunta: Como eu pego a string `Argumento1` e a string `Argumento2`, separada em duas variáveis nesse código duma linguagem que to fazendo:

```
if Argumento1 = Argumento2 (
     --statements;
   );
```

quero só pegar as duas variáveis, sem o outro texto. obrigado! (*prefiro a resposta em VB*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o [método `String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), dá para fazer assim:

```vb-net
Dim texto As String = "if Argumento1 = Argumento2 ( --statements; );"

Dim ifIndice As Integer = texto.IndexOf("if")
Dim igualIndice As Integer = texto.IndexOf("=")

Dim ifLen As Integer = Len("if") + 1

Dim argumento1 As String = texto.Substring(ifIndice + ifLen, igualIndice - ifLen)
Dim argumento2 As String = texto.Substring(igualIndice + 2, texto.IndexOf(" (") - igualIndice - 1)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Arg1: {0}, Arg2: {1}", argumento1, argumento2))
Console.ReadLine()
```

### [`Exemplo`](http://ideone.com/2NR35x)

Uma outra maneira usando [*expressões regulares*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```vb-net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
....
...

Dim texto As String = "if Argumento1 = Argumento2 ( --statements; );"
Dim argumento1 As String = "", argumento2 As String = ""

Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(texto, "if\s+([\w]+)\s+=\s+([\w]+)\s+\(", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If match.Success Then
     argumento1 = match.Groups(1).Value
     argumento2 = match.Groups(2).Value
End If
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Arg1: {0}, Arg2: {1}", argumento1, argumento2))
Console.ReadLine()
```

### [`Exemplo`](http://ideone.com/NVuKtm)

Comment: Opa, valeu ^-^.

Answer (score 2):

Há também uma função muito fina chamada Split

Ficaria algo assim:

```
Dim meuCodigo As String = "if Argumento1 = Argumento2 (--statements;);" 'Esse texto representa o seu código'

meuCodigo = meuCodigo.Replace("if ", "") 'Aqui nós substituimos uma parte do seu código que você não quer...'
meuCodigo = meuCodigo.Replace(" (--statements;);", "") 'Aqui substituimos outra parte também...'

Dim meuVetor() As String 'Aqui criamos uma variável que ira receber uma String e separar em 2 por um limitador'
meuVetor = Split(meuCodigo, " = ") 'Pronto, já separamos em 2!'

MsgBox("Argumento1: " & meuVetor(0) & vbNewLine & "Argumento2: " & meuVetor(1)) 'Aqui só exibimos uma mensagem do resultado'
```